Eigenvalues of general block tridiagonal matrix
Is there a general formula for the eigenvalues of matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} A & B & 0& \cdots& 0\\ B^*& A& B& \ddots &0\\0& B^*& A&\ddots&\vdots \\  \vdots&\ddots& \ddots&\ddots&B \\ 0&0&\cdots &B^*&A\end{bmatrix}?$$ Here, $A$, $B$ are n-by-n complex matrices.
In what I encountered, $A=\lambda I_n$ is a scalar matrix, but I was wondering if a general formula is known? If $B$ happens to be normal, then by the Spectral theorem, $B=UDU^*$ for some diagonal $D=\mbox{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. Hence, the matrix above is unitarily similar to $$\oplus_{i=1}^n \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & \lambda_i & 0& \cdots& 0\\ \overline{\lambda_i}& \lambda& \lambda_i& \ddots &0\\0& \overline{\lambda_i}& \lambda&\ddots&\vdots \\  \vdots&\ddots& \ddots&\ddots&\lambda_i \\ 0&0&\cdots &\overline{\lambda_i}&\lambda\end{bmatrix}.$$
If I'm not mistaken, the eigenvalues of each direct summand above are $\lambda+2|\lambda_i|\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi k}{n+1}\right)$ where $k=1,\ldots,n$. This gives a partial answer to the question.
But what if $A=\lambda I_n$ still but $B$ is not normal?

This might be useful
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349054391_On_the_characteristic_polynomial_eigenvalues_for_block_tridiagonal_matrices

@chhro I don't know how helpful this would be, but there is a nice approach that can be taken in the case that $A = \lambda I_n$ and $B$ is normal, i.e. $BB^* = B^*B$.

@BenGrossmann I added an attempt to what I think you're alluding to (please correct if wrong). Though I still am interested in the case when $B$ is not necessarily normal.

@chhro That's exactly right. I'm not sure about the more general case. I don't see anything particularly useful to be done using the SVD for instance
